# Why is copying from a network share over gigabit to a USB3 device slower than doing it in two steps?

Tags: network-shares, usb-3

I have a file on a network share that's about 500 MB.  When I copy it to my local drive, the copy reports about a 106 MB/sec which is reasonable for a gigabit network.  When I then copy the local file to a USB3 thumb drive, it's about 150 to 160 MB/sec, which is reasonable considering the specification of the thumb drive.  However, when I copy directly from the network share to my thumb drive, it maxes out at around 13 MB/sec.

What's going on here?  Why is the direct copy so much slower?

Additional info: Windows 7 PC, Core i7-3770K 3.5GHz, 8 GB RAM, 64-bit OS, solid state hard drive.  Thumb drive is a Kingston DTHX30/64GB.  USB port is 3.0 compatible and marked SS.

Comment: BTW this is a theory not an answer, however when copying across to USB from a UNC or network location it does cache the files before doing the USB transfer. So the bottleneck in my mind would be Motherboard BUS having to bring files in to Sata port then out to USB port. Again could be completely wrong but makes sense in my head.